# How to add columns in sprint board TFS (not backlog board)

Tags: tfs, kanban, sprint

In the newer versions I can customize the product backlog board by adding columns and set states. I want to do the same in the sprint board but  I can't find that functionality. I've change the way you can work with Bugs but it still don't give me the options I want. 
Pls Help

Comment: It is not possible today. It is a suggestion on User Voice: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3229015-customize-the-columns-on-the-task-board

Answer (score 3):

Not possible for Visual Studio Team Services(VSO) but for on-premise it is and is the same process since at least TFS 2012.

You will need to alter your process template for the Team Project to include the additional states. You can do this with either [TFS Power Tools](http://webstackoflove.com/create-custom-state-in-team-foundation-server-2013/) or I prefer to do it manually. You didn't specify what Process Template you are using so here it is for the SCRUM template (Others will be the same just will contain different wordings):

Export your WITD for Tasks from your dev machine via command line (I think it needs Team Explorer):

```
witadmin exportwitd /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:"TeamProjectName" /n:Task /f:"C:\FileToExportTo.xml"
```

Edit this file and find the **WORKFLOW** section and add in your new state into **STATES** e.g:

```
<STATE value="New State" />
```

Next, in the **TRANSITIONS** section add in the required transitions and any logic associated with it e.g:

```
<TRANSITION from="In Progress" to="New State">
  <REASONS>
    <DEFAULTREASON value="New State Started" />
  </REASONS>
</TRANSITION>
```

Save the file and import it again:

```
witadmin importwitd /collection:http://servername:8080/tfs  /p:"TeamProjectName" /f:"C:\FileToExportTo.xml"
```

You should export your entire process template and you should add those files to source control. If you want to do the same for Bugs or any other work item type then you will need to export and modify those WITD's too.